# Generic keyboard dismissal

Tags: android

Often when a fragment is detached, the soft keyboard remains. The fragment's view contains several EditText fields - is there a way to generically dismiss the keyboard without passing in the EditText which last had the focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your fragment's onDestroy() method, or via your own callback delegated to the parent activity, you should call the method below. There is no need to pass in a view:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}

public static void showSoftKeyboard(Activity activity, View view) {
    activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}

public static boolean isSoftKeyboardShowing(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    return inputMethodManager.isActive();
}
```